# BitBucket pipelines, set variable value at runtime

Tags: variables, bitbucket-pipelines

For my deployment I would like to be able to set the container tag at runtime. For example.

I have 2 containers:

container-1:1.0.2

container-2:0.1.0

I have a manually triggered deployment step.  I would like to be able to do something like this in my code:

`- helm install ${container_name}_chart --version=${helm_version} --set cotainer_version=${container_version}`

Where container_name, helm_version, and container_version are set by the user at runtime.

At runtime the user can enter (or even better, if possible select from a list) the container/app name and version.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can use runtime parameters with custom pipelines only.

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/pipeline-triggers/

```
    pipelines:
  custom:
    custom-name-and-region: #name of this pipeline
      - variables:          #list variable names under here
          - name: Username
          - name: Region
      - step: 
          script:
            - echo "User name is $Username"
            - echo "and they are in $Region"
```

Also, there is no drop down functionality.